# Detach HEAD before first commit

Tags: git

Is it possible to detach `HEAD` before the first commit in a new repo? If I try this I get an error:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/tim/test/.git/
$ git checkout -d
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

Best I can come up with is to make a commit and then delete the `master` branch, but that's a bit awkward for my code (this is for testing purposes). Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. From what you show in your question, it didn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot detach HEAD before the first commit in a repository, because detaching HEAD requires specifying a commit to check out, and you don't have any.

If your goal is to programmatically create commits that aren't referenced by any branch, you can use `git commit-tree` for that purpose.

Comment: Ah yes that's exactly what I want, thanks.